# two active network ports different subnets RHEL CentOS 7

Tags: network-interface, subnets

Can I have `eth0` as 151.x.x.x **and** `eth1` as 192.168.1.1 be active at the same time in RHEL 7?  If so how?

I am running RHEL 7.8 and it has one quad-port Intel NIC.

I would like to run a NAS off my `eth1` with the NAS having an IP of 192.168.1.2.  I want to use `rsnapshot` is linux where the NAS provides an NFS mountable folder `/bkup`.  However I do not want the NAS on the WAN, I want the NAS only physically accessible from [behind] my server.  I do not want the NAS exposed on the WAN.

With `eth0` active and working just fine if I turn on `eth1` then `eth0` automatically turns off and my server is off the WAN.  I figure I am missing something?

*my network vocabulary and knowledge isn't all that great, I know enough to be dangerous.*

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible!
Probably, the second interface shut down automatically because you have 2 default gateway configured.
Just remind that you can have only one default gateway, so chose from which ETH most of the traffic travels.
If you want to move certain packet trough a specific ETH, you can always configure network Routes.

Alessandro.